# Should the Exception.Message property be shown directly to users?

Tags: java, c#, oop, exception

That may sound like a silly question but I'd like to gather some input regarding this. I'm used to see 2 flavors of handling exception messages. First there is the simple pattern where you show the `Message` directly to the user:

```
try
{
    service.Update();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ShowMessage(ex.Message);
}
```

The alternative way of treating exceptions is to consider strongly-typed exceptions to mean something that is then interpreted by the 'controller' class (or whatever piece of code than handles pushing information to the user):

```
try
{
    service.Update();
}
catch (NetworkException ex)
{
    ShowMessage("Network is unavailable.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ShowMessage("Something went wrong with the update.");
}
```

The first approach requires that every message used by exceptions (whether passed in the constructor by the calling code or managed inside a strongly-typed exception) be 'user-ready' (clean, properly formulated and localized, etc.). The second approach transfers this responsibility to the controller code. Plus it might require having very specific strongly-typed exceptions to make sure that every catch block is able to interpret them correctly.

So to whom is aimed the Message property of the Exception class (in C#, Java...)? The end-user or the programmer?

Thank you,

Comment: And if you really want to expose something from `Exception`, use its `ToString()` method instead.  It delivers far more and better content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I feel that exception details (Message and StackTrace) are best left to logs at best.  Often times the exception text is too technical for display to the user and may actually give a malicious user information that could be used to hack or otherwise attack the system.

Thus, i would pick appropriate verbiage for different exceptions that is meaningful but not the actual technical details.

Of course, if this is a technical tool aimed at a particular technical audience, that may change things (like a database tool such as Toad may choose to show details of Oracle exceptions, etc).  But in general, I would avoid it.

Comment: All good answers so far but let's pick one the close the case. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

This question really depends on who your audience is and what type of information you want to give them. For most end users, ex.message will be meaningless and confusing. However, if you are writing specifically for programmers or for yourself, it could contain some useful information.

Comment: Bingo.  Another point to consider is that in situations where the programmer will have direct contact with the user but may not have direct access to the user's machine, having the user tell the programmer I got a 'fnord not woozled" message' may be easier than requiring the user to locate and email a log.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, users should never see a gritty exception message.

You should handle all exceptions you can foresee and give a useful message: `"Unable to load users..."` or something they can understand based on the task they tried to achieve.

For all unhandled exceptions you should have a standarised user-friendly message that tells them politely that something went wrong and perhaps display an error code from the method that means nothing to them and something to you.

On top of this, if you are logging all exceptions, which you should be doing, you can perhaps present the user with a log number for the error to help you track down the issue.

If appropriate, email exception details to yourself / the support team whenever they happen if you don't have access to the log/site.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad to answer. But a short answer is that you should always try to **show user what he understands**. *User friendly* messages are the way to go. And i don't think exceptions are useful enough for a novice user. So, one should always try to show him custom error messages and keep the exceptions for yourself. They are meant for you to **diagnose the error** and you should have access to them not user.